# How to number sections in LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Hello I'm new to latex so don't know much. I'm writing my lab report (prl,aps,revtex4-1 etc) and I want the sections to be numbered in Roman numerals but I can't seem to figure it out. For example my first section is introduction so  I've done

```
\section{Introduction}
```

so it just says introduction and it's not numbered

I've tried many things but nothing seems to work however i found this works

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

However I am also being marked on my coding (I'm a first year uni student)

I was wondering if this is the correct code for numbering sections and I'm not entirely sure what the number at the end means either please help.

Thank you :)

```
\begin{document}                     


\title{Example Lab Report} 
\date{Submitted: \today{}, Date of Experiment: EXPERIMENT DATE}
\author{A. Student (and L. Partner)}
\affiliation{\normalfont L1 Discovery Labs, Lab Group XXX, Lab Day}

\begin{abstract}              

ABSTRACT HERE

\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain} % produces page number for front page



\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal code reproducing the problem, that we can play with?

Comment: in the standard classes sections have level 1 and secnumdepth is 3 so sections are numbered by default, presumably you are using a non standard class that sets it (to 0?) to stop sections being numbered.

Comment: \begin{document}                     


\title{Example Lab Report} 
\date{Submitted: \today{}, Date of Experiment: EXPERIMENT DATE}
\author{A. Student (and L. Partner)}
\affiliation{\normalfont L1 Discovery Labs, Lab Group XXX, Lab Day}

\begin{abstract}              
 
ABSTRACT HERE

\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain} 



\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\section{Introduction}

Comment: is that enough code for you ?

Comment: david carlisle I'm not going to lie i have no idea what you said xD

Comment: What is your preamble?

Comment: \documentclass[prl,aps,superscriptaddress,twocolumn,10pt]{revtex4-1}    is this what you mean by preamble

Comment: anything between the `documentclass` and the `\begin{document}` is the preamble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prd` as the journal.

```
\documentclass[
  prd,
  aps,
  superscriptaddress,
  twocolumn,
  10pt,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}                     


\title{Example Lab Report} 
\date{Submitted: \today{}, Date of Experiment: EXPERIMENT DATE}
\author{A. Student (and L. Partner)}
\affiliation{\normalfont L1 Discovery Labs, Lab Group XXX, Lab Day}

\begin{abstract}              

ABSTRACT HERE

\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain} % produces page number for front page

\section{Introduction} 

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Tests} 

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still don't get it what does lipsum mean ?  and why have you put the numbers 1-2 ??

Comment: @mavihs26 `\lipsum[1-2]` is just for producing dummy text. The package is not necessary for a real document.

Comment: Changing to prd fixed it nevermind.  Thank you for your help